# HornetQ Reconnect-attempts not working with DefaultMessageListenerContainer

Tags: java, jms, hornetq, spring-jms

I've configured spring for jms listener to consume messages from hornetQ as follows.

```
<bean name="connectionFactory" class="com.kp.jms.KPHornetQJMSConnectionFactory"
    destroy-method="close">
    <constructor-arg name="ha" type="boolean" value="false" />
    <constructor-arg>
        <array>
            <ref bean="transportConfiguration"></ref>
        </array>
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="maxRetryInterval" value="10000" />
    <property name="reconnectAttempts" value="10" />
    <property name="retryInterval" value="5000" />
    <property name="retryIntervalMultiplier" value="2" />
    <property name="initialConnectAttempts" value="10" />
</bean>

<bean name="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"></property>
</bean>


<bean name="kpJmsDelegator"
    class="com.kp.KPDelegator">
    <property name="jmsTemplate" ref="jmsTemplate"></property>
</bean>


<jms:listener-container connection-factory="connectionFactory"
    concurrency="1"  >
    <jms:listener destination="kpQueue" ref="kpJmsDelegator"
        method="onMessage" />
</jms:listener-container>
```

The code works fine when the hornetq server is up and running. However when I start the application and without starting the hornetq I'm getting, `could not find queue in warn mode every 5seconds. which I found that the DefaultMessageListenerContainer class sets the default recovery time to 5seconds`. However I'm expecting the recovery settings to be considered from connection factory and use recovery attempts to be for 10times and if still could not connect give the reconnect resulting in manual restart of the server if jms to reactivate. Since reattempt is not considered my log is bombarded with error message. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong, could someone point out what is the mistake I'm doing?

Here is the stack trace

```
014-04-24 18:27:27,159 [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#1-227] WARN  o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer - Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'snmpQueue' - trying to recover. Cause: There is no queue with name kpQueue
javax.jms.JMSException: There is no queue with name snmpQueue
    at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQSession.createQueue(HornetQSession.java:407) ~[hornetq-jms-2.2.21.Final.jar:2.2.21.SNAPSHOT (HQ_2_2_21_final, 122)]
    at org.springframework.jms.support.destination.DynamicDestinationResolver.resolveQueue(DynamicDestinationResolver.java:101) ~[spring-jms-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.support.destination.DynamicDestinationResolver.resolveDestinationName(DynamicDestinationResolver.java:66) ~[spring-jms-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.support.destination.JmsDestinationAccessor.resolveDestinationName(JmsDestinationAccessor.java:100) ~[spring-jms-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.createListenerConsumer(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:221) ~[spring-jms-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.initResourcesIfNecessary(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1119) ~[spring-jms-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1095) ~[spring-jms-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1088) ~[spring-jms-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:985) ~[spring-jms-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [na:1.6.0_32]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However I'm expecting the recovery settings to be considered from connection factory and use recovery attempts to be for 10times

Both attributes are not part of the `ConnectionFactory` contract so there is no way for `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` to figure that out.

You can rewrite your config as follows to use a 10 sec recovery interval:

```
<jms:listener-container connection-factory="connectionFactory"
                        concurrency="1" recovery-interval="10000">
    <jms:listener destination="kpQueue" ref="kpJmsDelegator"
                  method="onMessage" />
</jms:listener-container>
```

There is no way to limit the number of recoveries but it should be fairly easy for you to extend from `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` and create your own extension of `recoverAfterListenerSetupFailure`. You could retry a number of times and if that's not working, you could call `stop` on the container to stop listening on that queue. That means that if the broker is failing and resume after 20 min or so, your listener won't be enabled anymore...

Comment: Is there any other option like using SimpleMessageListenerContainer or delegators?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: I was asking are there any other classes other than DefaultMessageListenerContainer where retry-attempt limit can be set. I tried to use SimpleMessageListenerContainer but application startup failed with bean creation error.

Comment: Like I already said in my answer, there's no such feature currently. I'll update my answer to make that explicit

Comment: Yeah..... Fair enough................. Thanks a lot........ will rise JIRA in springframework......... mean time I will extend DefaultMessageListenerContainer and try fix this issue. Thanks a lot for input